# Can you preallocate space for a String in Julia?

Tags: arrays, string, performance, memory-management, julia

The Julia documentation describes [pre-allocating memory](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/?highlight=preallocate#pre-allocating-outputs) for an `Array` to improve performance by avoiding garbage collection.  Is this possible to do with a `String` which is a Vector, after all? `String` source code is [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/5151271f7d0a12bdfecac496c5f46959d8679252/base/strings/string.jl).

My use case is that I am processing large text dumps, using `readuntil()` to get a chunk, then doing regex `match()` or `matchall()` or `replace()`.  I already coded it in Perl, but want to see if Julia can be faster.  I already know the length of the longest string I will have to process.

```
fs=open(fn,"r")
    while !eof(fs)
        text = readuntil(fs, "</tag>")
        text = match(r"pattern"s, text).match
        text = replace(text, r"badpattern", "goodpattern")
        text = replace(text, r"anotherbadpattern", "betterpattern")
        ... (dozens more replacements)
    end
close(fs)
```

I expect disk I/O to be the main bottleneck, but am interested in learning about anything that will help.  I welcome any suggestions on possible methods to speed up the process.

Comment: The source code you've linked to is a constructor for `String` that takes a `Vector` as input, but it is not the type definition itself (which, as @slowbrain points out, is immutable).

Comment: Can you add the more specific code sample?

Comment: @DanGetz Added a code example.  What I was hoping was not to have to (re-)allocate the `text` string several million times as there are a lot of loops to collect the <tag>ed text and many replacements.  I was hoping to use Julia's regex capabilities since I already coded this in Perl, but as @ColinTBowers and @slowbrain have pointed out, String is immutable, so not able to be reallocated.

Comment: Can you give us timings comparing the Perl and Julia versions? The code in my answer decreases allocation of `replace` by 50%. Turns out `text` is not the only thing allocated. Do you know if Perl does allocations?

Answer (score 6):

Strings in Julia are immutable therefore the concept of pre-alocation does not work.

```
julia> a = "aaaa";
julia> pointer(a)
   Ptr{UInt8} @0x0000000119628f50

julia> a = "bbbb";
julia> pointer(a)
   Ptr{UInt8} @0x000000011963a030
```

Answer (score 3):

First,

> "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" *-- Donald Knuth*

Having said that, the `replace` code in Base show it reads the source String and finds matches to replace and it writes parts of the resulting String into an IOBuffer. After processing it reads the output String from the IOBuffer. Essentially, this does two copies of the source String. If a maximum length of the input String (and hence also the output) is known, the IOBuffer in `replace` can be reused instead of allocated.

To put this analysis into code, define the following `replace!` (based on `replace`):

```
function replace!(out::IOBuffer, str::String, pattern, repl, limit::Integer)
  n = 1
  e = endof(str)
  i = a = start(str)
  r = search(str,pattern,i)
  j, k = first(r), last(r)
  Base.ensureroom(out, floor(Int, 1.2sizeof(str)))
  while j != 0
    if i == a || i <= k
      Base.write_sub(out, str.data, i, j-i)
      Base._replace(out, repl, str, r, pattern)
    end
    if k<j
      i = j
      k = nextind(str, j)
    else
      i = k = nextind(str, k)
    end
    if j > e
      break
    end
    r = search(str,pattern,k)
    j, k = first(r), last(r)
    n == limit && break
    n += 1
  end
  write(out, SubString(str,i))
  takebuf_string(out)
end

replace!(out::IOBuffer,s::AbstractString, pat, f, n::Integer) =
  replace!(out, String(s), pat, f, n)
replace!(out::IOBuffer,s::AbstractString, pat, r) =
  replace!(out, s, pat, r, 0)
```

And now,

```
const string1 = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
const out = IOBuffer(100)

replace!(out,string1,"quick","slow")
```

will perform a replacement without allocating the IOBuffer. After the `replace!`, `out` can be reused (it is back to being empty by `takebuf_string` in `replace!`. Benchmarking shows this reduces allocation by 50% and speeds up the process as well. If many `replace` statements are used, as you suggest in the question this should give a 30% or more improvement.

If you try this, it would be nice to hear a real world benchmark result. Perhaps some version of `replace!` should be put into Base.

Answer (score 1):

In Julia 0.6 it is easier to attempt an even more optimized version. Specifically, we can have an IOBuffer and a String share the same memory. The `replace` function writes to an IOBuffer and processes a String, so this gives us the opportunity to do `replace!` without any allocations.

A series of `replace!` statements can alternate between two pre-allocated buffers and (almost) avoid any allocation.

More concretely:

```
# version 0.6.0-pre.alpha.220
function replace!(out::IOBuffer, str::AbstractString, 
  pattern, repl, limit::Integer)
    n = 1
    e = endof(str)
    i = a = start(str)
    r = search(str,pattern,i)
    j, k = first(r), last(r)
    out.size = 0
    out.ptr = 1
    while j != 0
        if i == a || i <= k
            Base.unsafe_write(out, pointer(str, i), UInt(j-i))
            Base._replace(out, repl, str, r, pattern)
        end
        if k<j
            i = j
            k = nextind(str, j)
        else
            i = k = nextind(str, k)
        end
        if j > e
            break
        end
        r = search(str,pattern,k)
        j, k = first(r), last(r)
        n == limit && break
        n += 1
    end
    write(out, SubString(str,i))
  return out.ptr-1
end
```

And to drive this function and pre-allocate buffers we do:

```
const string1 = "."^1000
const string2 = "."^1000

const io1 = IOBuffer(convert(Vector{UInt8},string1),true,true,length(string1))
const io2 = IOBuffer(convert(Vector{UInt8},string2),true,true,length(string2))

write(io1,"hello world. "^30)   # test string to manipulate

function switcheroo!()
    replace!(io2,SubString(string1,1,io1.ptr-1),"hello","what's up",0)
    replace!(io1,SubString(string2,1,io2.ptr-1),"what's up","hello",0)
end

switcheroo!()
```

The function `switcheroo!` replaces `hello` with `whats up` and back again. It is simple to modify the code to handle a series of `replace` as the question suggests is required.

Notes:

1. This is more closely coupled with Julia String internals and thus may not be stable going forward to future Julia versions (but just as efficient alternatives will probably remain).
2. There are still two (pesky!) allocations per `replace!` for the two SubString values created. These allocations are 64 bytes and do not grow with string size.

Comment: You are way too fast for my programming abilities!  Both of your answers are great.  I am still testing the previous `replace!()` you created and trying to figure out comparable Perl timings and account for disk access.  I don't think I'll get to this one until v0.6 comes out ;)